# What is the simplest way to launch asynchronous API requests inside a for loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a "get_data" function which make an API request and returns a dataframe of finacial data. I would like to make something like this:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    df = my_api.get_data(ticker)
    
// wait here for all api requests to complete
```

How do I use asyncio (or something similar) to get launch all API requests simultaneously from for loop and wait for all requests to complete?

I tried this but it executes the 1st ticker once, then both tickers:

```
def foo(tickers):
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for ticker in tickers:
        # await asyncio.sleep(0)
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, get_data(ticker))
        
    loop.run_forever()

foo(tickers)
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `get_data(ticker)`? Usually that _calls_ the `get_data` function right there, and then calls the _return_ of the function asynchronously. Instead, do `run_in_executor(..., get_data, ticker)`

Comment: If you’re just going to run everything in an executor, you might be better off just using concurrent.futures instead of asyncio.

Comment: but @PranavHosangadi definitely has the right answer for the OP's stated issue. don't call the function while submitting the job.